# Power BI compound percentage growth for years for future prediction

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to make a calculation in power bi taking initial hours and total hours value from measure and numeric input from user to predict yearly increase rate for 5 years.
Ex: Initial value is 745 and total value is 3336. And 3 is input from user so that one can predict the changes in future if they want to increase the data by any percentage.
And Inputs are always captured from measure and user numeric input.
How can I do this.

[image]